# How to apply different .htaccess rules based on the uri

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website running on ExpressionEngine and a custom backoffice based on Zend.
Both approaches expect a specific htaccess file placed in the root.

This is my structure.

- http://localhost/... (ExpressionEngine pages, eg. http://localhost/calendar/events)
- http://localhost/backoffice (Backoffice pages)

Before placing the backoffice on a subdomain, I wanted to know if it's possibile to have one htacces file and to apply a different set of htaccess rules based on the uri. So eg. everything with "backoffice" gets different rules.

I know you can do stuff like this:
Best I've found was the following [Can I do an if/then/else in htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234919/can-i-do-an-if-then-else-in-htaccess)
But I'm stuck with defined the variables based on the uri.

Thanks for your help.

regards
Vic

Answer (score 0):

Put your rewrite rules for EE first and add a rule for the back office there:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/backoffice
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

And now add the rules for the back office.

Comment: Tnx for your answer.
Another subdomain was still necessary, because there were 2 different index.php files needed, one for Zend and one for EE.